# Check jQuery tag-it input via getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tag-it

I'm searching for a away to check newly added tag in tag-it (http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it) via getJSON request and allow adding tag with (eventually) edited tagName or disallow adding new tag.

For example: Entering "audi s3" will trigger beforeTagAdded event which should do the getJSON request, response from server will contain something like "Audi S3" or "Audi S3, 2007".

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: allow or disallow based on what?  Please put a little more effort into question explanation and be specific about what your issue is. As it stands right now it we have no idea what your problem is

Comment: I've tried to call 

$.getJSON("/foo.php", { var : 'foo' ], function( response) {}, { async : false } )

but the call is not async so tag is created without waiting for return of getJSON().

@charlietfl: Decision is made on base of internal rules, i.e. creating a tag "BMW" will not be allowed. I didn't write about it because this does not affect the problem at all.

Comment: still not clear what your problem is.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to call getJSON and wait for response before boolean true or false is returned to tag-it